# Realtime log parsing

Tags: logging, real-time, high-load

I want to write a tool which parses log files at realtime. Log file can be written very fast, for example ~10k lines per second. I just need to get each line, then execute one regexp and write result to DB. Due to speed, it couldn't be done by reading file entirely, so I need to write alternative to something like `tail -f`.
Tell me, please, how, and using what technology can I do this?

P.S. Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your logs in RAM-partition, with log-rotate limited to 512MB.
So you'll be limited by the capacity of RAM with its high speed.

If your specify what application produces your logs, I can tell more.
Have you tried for your tasks http://goaccess.io/?